# QML How to paint different to grabToImage()

Tags: qt, qml

Is there any possible way to make `grabToImage()` buffer different from what's displayed in GUI? I'm using `ChartView` without legend in GUI and want to export it to `PNG` with legend. So I try:

```
chartView.legend.visible = true
chartView.update()
chartView.grabToImage(function(result) {
    console.log("grabbed")

    var path = filename.toString().replace(/^(file:\/{2})/,"");
    console.log(path + result.saveToFile(path));
    chartView.legend.visible = false
    update();
});
```

But both those updates happen only after the control comes out of this function, so I don't get legend drawn in PNG. Also I would like the appearance of legend to be unnoticable to user. Are there any ways to do that in QML?

Comment: You can try to create a second invisible ChartView and use a Timer to let Qt some time to process everything before you save it to PNG.

Comment: @m7913d , that's a not too straight-forward way, but I'll try =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am unsure, whether I got you quite right.

My suggestion is, to not grab the `Item` you display, but a copy of it, that you then modify as you like.
*Copy* here does not mean, that you have the same object twice, but that you render it twice by using a [`ShaderEffectSource`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shadereffectsource.html). Before you grab this `ShaderEffectSource` to image, you can add anything you like.

In my example I display a simple `Rectangle` with a nice gradient. What I save is the same `Rectangle` that is extended by the `Text` 'I am legend'. The user won't see this text apearing in the view at any time.

```
Rectangle {
    id: commonView
    width: 200
    height: 200
    gradient: Gradient {
        GradientStop { position: 0; color: 'steelblue' }
        GradientStop { position: 1; color: 'orange' }
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        // don't grab the rectangle itself.
        onClicked: legendView.grabToImage(function(result) {
            console.log(result.saveToFile("something.png"));
        });
    }
}

ShaderEffectSource {
    id: legendView
    visible: false // Does not need to be shown.
    sourceItem: commonView
    width: 200
    height: 200
    Text {
        anchors {
            right: parent.right
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
        text: 'I am legend'
    }
}
```

You might optimize the performance by only having the `ShaderEffectSource` active or even created when needed.

You might use the `ShaderEffectSource.live`-property to disable updating of it. Then use `scheduleUpdate()` to trigger the update.

This might look like this:

```
Rectangle {
    id: commonView
    width: 200
    height: 200
    gradient: Gradient {
        GradientStop { position: 0; color: 'steelblue' }
        GradientStop { id: gs1; position: 1; color: 'orange' }
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            gs1.position -= 0.1
            legendView.save()
        }
    }
}

ShaderEffectSource {
    id: legendView
    y: 200
    visible: false // Do not render it (will only be rendered when called grapToImage()
    sourceItem: commonView
    width: 200
    height: 200
    live: false // Will only be updated, when explicitly called for
    function save() {
        console.log('Schedule Save')
        scheduleUpdate() // explicitly update. grabToImage() will force rendering afterwards.
        legendView.grabToImage(function(result) {
                        console.log(result.saveToFile("something" +gs1.position.toFixed(1) + ".png"));
                    })
    }

    // Put additional stuff on it.
    Text {
        anchors {
            right: parent.right
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
        text: 'I am legend!'
    }
}
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what was suggested in comments, but in my case that's not a good solution: due to performance reasons I can't simultaneously change both charts series (which are added dynamically), thus I should then create a copy of that chart when user wants to take a snapshot. Anyway it would require to double the chart - double the memory used, and that might become a huge bottleneck.

Comment: You don't double the data. The `ShaderEffectSource` copies only the visual representation. You only have one `ChartView`. Maybe I need to clarify my answer to point that out.

Comment: Ok, I start to understand, that's an interesting thing. But there is another problem: I would like to paint legend using `ChartView`'s methods. But I don't know how to disable updating the `commonView` so that legend doesn't appear on it. Sure, if that's not possible at all, I can switch to painting legend myself the same way you do it with `Text`.

Comment: This seems to be problematic. I don't have `QtCharts` installed, but it seems the `Legend` is no `Item` and therefore might not be suitable as source for a `ShaderEffectSource`. Otherwise you might turn it `visible: false` and replace my `Text` by another `ShaderEffectSource` with source: `chartView.legend` which then should be visible again on the saved image. You might try it (maybe it is, though undocumented, and Item) - I don't know if it will work.

Comment: Wow. I would definitely try that. Legend is just boolean, but maybe there is some undocumented legend item inside